# How to automate Django - React app deployment

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, automation

I have Django as backend and React as frontend, my current deployment process is I use WinSCP to transfer react build to django backend and then with Putty I use
`python manage.py collectstatic.`
Then I update git repo at aws, do migrations (if any) manually.

I want to automate this in way that There is no need to build and copy react to backend also not to pull current repo changes or use WinSCP or Putty etc. I just want simple script or any standard way by which, whenever I update code in my production branch at backend and frontend, deployment will be done automatically. Pls suggest me the way. TIA

Comment: You need to implement CI/CD pipeline. You can look into Jenkins, CircleCI, AWS CodeBuild, Travis CI etc.

Comment: add Github Actions to the list above if you're using github as your repo.